# Word for when someone pretends to be weak, but is really strong

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a one-word substitute for when someone outwardly shows that he is weak, just to deceive others, but in reality he is strong? And what is a person called who performs such a trick?

Comment: Depends on the context. Could be a staffer or toady. Could be a general hiding his army.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're looking for the word ***sandbagging***:

> 2d :  to conceal or misrepresent one's true position, potential, or intent especially in order to take advantage of
>
> By the 1940s, [*sandbagging*] was being used of a strategy in which a poker player with a good hand bets weakly, in order to draw other players into holding on to their hands and raising the bet. The use of *sandbag* has since evolved to refer to a general strategy of playing down one's position in order to gain some sort of advantage.
>
> *from [M-W.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandbag)*

The person who engages in such a tactic is generally called a ***sandbagger***.

Comment: Thanks. I was specifically looking for this word. I had read about it but was unable to recall the word.

Answer (score 7):

**Hustler**, Conman, Swindler, etc.

[Hustler definition from Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hustler)

> noun
>
> 1.
>   an enterprising person determined to succeed; go-getter.
>
> 2.
>   Slang. a person who employs fraudulent or unscrupulous methods to obtain money; swindler.

Comment: Hustler is a good choice, but the reason why isn't properly explained in those definitions.  One of the definitions of "hustle" is to pretend to be bad at something in order to make a bet with someone over a game (eg of pool or basketball), and then reveal during the game that you're actually very good at it, and proceed to beat the other person and win the bet.

Answer (score 3):

This person is [feigning](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20feign) weakness:

> pretend to be affected by (a feeling, state, or injury).
>
> - "she feigned nervousness"
>
> synonyms: simulate, fake, sham, affect, give the appearance of, make a
>   pretense of
>
> - "she lay still and feigned sleep"
>
> pretend, put it on, fake, sham, bluff, masquerade, play-act; kid
>
> - "he's not really ill, he's only feigning"
>
> pretended, simulated, affected, artificial, insincere, put-on, fake,
>   false, sham;
>
> pretend, phony
>
> - "he accepted the invitation with feigned enthusiasm"

Answer (score 0):

**Masquerade** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/masquerade)

> 1. Pretend to be someone one is not
>
> *"a journalist masquerading as a man in distress"*

This can be used both ways: to appear stronger than one is, or to appear weaker than one is.